# how to get a value and an array present inside a list

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I want to get a value from an array inside list. Each list value contains an array, I want to get a singe value from that array.

**Mail.java**

```
properties = new Properties("server_url.properties");
    dataAccess = new DataAccess(properties);
    List<Map<String,String>> resp = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() ;
    List<Map<String,String>> obj = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() ;
        resp=dataAccess.getApplications();
        obj=dataAccess.getServers();
            //System.out.println(resp.get(0));

            MailServer sender = new MailServer(Constants.setFrom, Constants.setPassword);

            try {
            sender.sendMail("Demo Apps & Server Status","The Following Applications are DOWN" + '\n'+
                    '\n' + resp.get(0) + '\n'+
                    '\n'+ "The Following servers are DOWN" +'\n'
                    + '\n' + obj.get(2)
                    ,Constants.setFrom,Constants.emailTO);
        }
               catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Email was not sent...");

        }  

            System.out.println("Email Sent Succesfully...");

        }
```

If I run the above code ,I get the following list values

**Output**

```
{DataBase=Oracle, Links=192.168.215.158:1521:sscdb01, status=UP, 192.168.215.158:151:sscdb01=UP, name=Claim Status, WebServices=}
{Links=https://mobile.infotech.com:8090, status=UP, ssl_exp_date=Mon Apr 18 14:42:45 IST 2016, https://mobile.infotech.com:8090=UP, name=com}
```

From the above value I just want to get two values -  name and Status values without getting all the values from the list value

Answer (score 2):

Simply invoke `get` on your desired key to get the value in your `Map` (i.e. **not** array).

For instance:

```
resp.get(0).get("name")
resp.get(0).get("status")
```

I strongly recommend checking for `null` values. Something in the lines of:

```
// checking: list not empty, index x < list size, indexed item at x not null
if (!resp.isEmpty() && resp.size() > x && resp.get(x) != null)) {
    // checking: value for key "name" not null
    if (resp.get(x).get("name") != null) {
         String foo = resp.get(x).get("name");
    }
}
```

... where `x` is your desired `List` index. Example above could be improved by assigning to references instead of invoking `get` over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
 resp.get(0).get(key);
```

Same is the case with obj as well

Answer (score 1):

```
resp.get(index).get("name")
resp.get(index).get("status")
```

Comment: A little explanation of your answer would be useful to the questioner and also to others that find this answer later.